# ElasticSearch: Weird problem in inserting documents to ElasticSearch indices when a template is present

Tags: elasticsearch, fiddler, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-template

I am trying to do some testing in ElasticSearch. I am able to populate everything as required but whenever I try to put our project's default template and then insert, the data is not ingested in the index (http calls are successful though).

Upon inspection, I realised that I can't insert even a simple document even after using elasticSearch's default template.
For example inserting the template from ES's documentation:

```
PUT _template/template_1
{
  "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "host_name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "created_at": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then inserting a doc in `index = "bark"` by

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/bark/_doc/11232 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9200
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json

{"host_name": "generic_name"}
```

adds a doc in the index but without the data about the `host_name`.
Simply changing the index name to something for which this template does not apply (like `index = dark`) will add a doc with the data about `host_name`.
Showing index data for replication:

(when `index=bark`)

```
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"bark","_type":"_doc","_id":"11232","_score":1.0}]}}
```

(when `index=dark`)

```
{"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":{"value":1,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"dark","_type":"_doc","_id":"11232","_score":1.0,"_source":{"host_name":"generic_name"}}]}}
```

Notice the `_source":{"host_name":"generic_name"}` field is absent in the former?

What could be done for this? If someone has faced this issue or knows a fix, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove this from your mapping

```
"_source": {
  "enabled": false
},
```

The effect of this setting is that the source document is not stored in the `_source` field. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: Hi,
This does not seem to be the issue though.
I have tried to make `"enabled": true` and completely removing the field 

`"_source": {
  "enabled": false
}`
Neither has made any difference

Comment: Did you delete the index after making the change to the template?

Comment: Yes, This was the issue.
Thank you!